Is Google's Project Aristotle based on a published study?
Google's Project Aristotle (wayback machine) is relatively well known in the tech world. It emphasizes the important relationship between psychological safety and team productivity. On a few occasions, I've attempted to find the source material of the study, but I've never succeeded.
This 2020 NIH article mentions Project Aristotle, but it links back to the old rework.withgoogle.com site that no longer exists (except in Japanese). I browsed the site back when the English version existed, and couldn't find a basis for their findings then, either.
Is Project Aristotle based on a published study? If so, how do I find it?
